# Postpone reminders on iPhone XR

Tags: reminders

On a phone with 3D touch it is possible to postpone a reminder from the lock screen (one hour, tomorrow) or mark it as complete.

iPhone XR lacks 3D touch, and if the reminder pops up **when the phone is unlocked** it is possible to slide down the reminder and the three options reappear.

When the phone is on the lock screen, **even if unlocked with face ID**, iOS shows the message but does not give the possibility to slide down.

If I then go to the home screen I cannot see the reminder anymore.

My question: is there a way to postpone a reminder on an iPhone without 3D touch as the iPhone XR?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Press you finger hard against the screen over the reminder in the home screen and let go. If you have haptic feedback on, you will feel it. This will open the menu for snooze or mark as complete the reminder.

Comment: This will work on iPhones with 3D Touch. Without it you have to slide on the left and choose the option in the middle.